# How to find particular column unique values count in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe.,

```
company,sector,marks
a,b1,21
b,b2,27
c,b2,20
a,b3,70
```

I have to display no of company,sector and sum of marks
how do we take unique column value length in pandas

Comment: IIUC you can do `df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts)`

Comment: please post desired output / DF

Comment: i need output like company:3,sector:3,marks:138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print (pd.Series([df.company.nunique(),
                  df.sector.nunique(),
                  df.marks.sum()], index=df.columns))


company      3
sector       3
marks      138
dtype: int64

print (pd.Series([df.company.nunique(),
                  df.sector.nunique(),
                  df.marks.sum()], index=df.columns).to_dict())
{'company': 3, 'sector': 3, 'marks': 138}
```

Or:

```
print (pd.Series([df.company.nunique(),
                  df.sector.nunique(),
                  df.marks.sum()], index=df.columns).to_json())
{"company":3,"sector":3,"marks":138}
```

If need custom names:

```
print (pd.Series([df.company.nunique(),
                  df.sector.nunique(),
                  df.marks.sum()], index=['comp','sec','mar']))

comp      3
sec       3
mar     138
dtype: int64
```

Comment: dat=(pd.Series([data['Company-Ace'].unique(),
                  data['Ambit Sector'].unique(),
                  data['Market Cap'].sum()], index=data[['Company-Ace','Ambit Sector','Market Cap']]).to_dict())

Comment: ooops , this is better `dat= pd.Series([data['Company-Ace'].nunique(), data['Ambit Sector'].nunique(), data['Market Cap'].sum()], index=['Company-Ace','Ambit Sector','Market Cap']).to_dict()`